# Cannot download file using ThinDownloadManager library in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am developing my first Android project. In my project, I need to download mp3 file. So I am using ThinDownloadManager library to download mp3 file easily. But it is not downloading file.

I installed library using grandle

```
compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.2.1'
```

This is my download function

```
private void downloadPodcast(int id)
    {
        String url = context.getResources().getString(R.string.api_endpoint)+"?id="+String.valueOf(id);

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(context.getExternalCacheDir().toString()+"/test.mp3");
        DownloadRequest downloadRequest =
                new DownloadRequest(downloadUri).setDestinationURI(destinationUri).setPriority(DownloadRequest.Priority.HIGH);
    }
```

It is not downloading anything. I access the URL directly, it is downloading. But when download using this code by button click event, it is not working. Why it is not working?

Comment: It is not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, u created download request, and think that is all?
U need do some more to download:
Put this to Your class:

```
ThinDownloadManager downloadManager=new ThinDownloadManager();
```

Then in Your download function add:

```
downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);
```